# How to access application resources in code, c#, wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know you can access page resources by using the following code:

```
btn.Style = Resources["ButtonStle"] as Style;
```

But how do you access an application wide resource?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the application through the static Application.Current property.

```
btn.Style = Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle"] as Style;
```